# How to set "view full site" link in the mobile theme?

Tags: magento-1.7, theme, mobile, theme-fallback

I am creating a **mobile theme** for the magento store so that the **same url(e.g. example.com)** for the store when watched in the mobile devices then it will look differently.

I have added the exception feature of magento in the admin site for the mobile devices.

Now in the footer I **want to keep a link** called "**View full site**" which when clicked , should show the other theme which is used for the desktop view.
How can I do this ?

Comment: have you created to two store (1 desktop & 2 mobile)?

Comment: no I'm restricted to do that ..

Comment: desktop theme & mobile theme apply same store?

Comment: yes you are right.@Abdul

Comment: e.g. example.com/?___store=default is desktop & e.g. example.com/?___store=mobile

Comment: means your creates two store default  & mobile ?

Comment: No. The same url is for both mobile and desktop view . e.g example.com

Comment: follow the accepted answer in the following page.....
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96905/class-not-found-error-while-extending-core-helper

Answer (score 1):

You have to build a small module and rewrite the ***design_package*** model in Magento.

See instructions in this article: http://www.classyllama.com/blog/switching-desktop-when-using-design-exceptions-custom-mobile-theme

Comment: I am facing problem implementing the above instuctions.I have uploaded the module in respective folder.but there is an error coming as " Class 'Mage_Cls_Designswitcher_Helper_Data' not found".. But the helper class is "CLS_DesignSwitcher_Helper_Data".

Answer (score 0):

When you click on this link you can set a cookie that you can use to load the mobile theme or the original one.